# Update google contact with php api

Tags: php

Hi since fews days my php script to update google contact failed.

```
$url='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{google_email_account}/full/{id_contacts}';

$options = [
  'headers' => [
    'If-Match' => '*',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml',
    'GData-Version' => '3.0',
  ],
  'body' => $atom
];

$response = $httpClient->put($url,$options);
```

the reponse :

["message":protected]=>
  string(176) "Client error: `PUT https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{google_email_account}/full/{id_contacts}` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
Invalid XML Document.

the XML is the same.

thank

Comment: _"the XML is the same"_  can you verify that? What's in `$atom`? How is it generated?